# Using the same ultrasonic transducer for Tx and Rx in distance measurement

Tags: audio, filter, multiplexer, low-pass

Goal:

- Measure distance to surrounding objects using 5 automotive grade
  ultrasonic transducers mounted to different points on a small robot.

Requirements:

- Multiplex the drive and receive pulses so only one drive and
  receive(conditioning) circuit is required to drive all 5 transducers.
- Each transducer should be able to send outgoing pulses and receive echo.
- Transducer excitation voltage is 150V with resonant frequency of 48kHz

Problem:

- I am able to drive the transducers with a 150Vpp 48kHz pulse train (5
  pulses) as shown below on the oscilloscope, but I am stumped on the
  receiving side. There is so much ringing in the circuit after the 150Vpp
  transmit that it overwhelms the small ~100mV echo signal. Furthermore, the switching from the relays is adding it's own noise.

Question:

- Is it possible to mux the transducers like I am trying to do? If not, do you know of a solution using common components? All chip solutions are unavailable.
- What is a solution to quickly dampen the oscillation in the circuit after the transmit but then allow for the transducer to receive the echo? My best guess is higher order filtering.

[image]

- Yellow trace is the output of the driver circuit, probed at "piezo_tx" in the schematic. The probe is set to 10x so the Vpp is actually around 150Vpp
- The blue trace is the "echo_in" net. Probe set to 1x.
- The vertical yellow lines are the time gap that I expect to see from transmit to echo received.
  [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are a number of possible sources of the ringing you're finding. As a first tweak, can you change your relay circuit and relay logic drive so the transducer(s) is connected to a load resistor after completing the transmit pulse? Then release that connection before you expect echoes to begin arriving. The transducers are highly resonant and the resistor may act as a brake to dissipate the stored energy. It might also work with a dead short instead of a resistor.  It's also possible the chassis the transducers are mounted on is actually ringing. Can you soft-mount them?

Comment: Also, try a patent search for "ringing in ultrasonic transducers." Here's one result: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6731569B2/en

Comment: Reducing transducer's resonant Q can be done with added inductor and resistance (which improves the ring-down speed). But it also reduces the sensor's sensitivity too. An expected 100mV echo amplitude seems large - this will become much smaller from a de-Q'd piezo. An electrical characterization model of that 48kHz piezo may help - does your piezo data sheet give info of its equivalent circuit?

Comment: It is difficult to use the same ultrasonic transducer. It is intentionally resonant with a moderately high Q and thus will ring for a long time. Can you use the automotive ultrasonic sensors with integrated electronics? - They have a digital interface so multiple sensors can easily be controlled by a single microprocessor.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Thanks for the welcome and reply! I hadn't thought of looking into the patent world so I thank you for that suggestion. According to that paper I may have to apply a different circuit to the transducer during transmit and receive, which makes a lot of sense. Looks like I'll likely have to build in a snubbing circuit and switch it in between tx and rx.

Comment: @glen_geek You're right 100mV is most likely higher than what I'll see in practical application, if I can get it working. That's just what I was seeing on bench top testing with small distances. I think that I'll end up having to do something like you're saying with the ring down circuit, but only apply it briefly between rx and tx, if possible. Unfortunately the data sheet doesn't give an equivalent circuit, just a few parameters. But if you're curious the one I'm using is CUSA-TR60-06-2000-WC68

Comment: @KevinWhite It may ultimately come to using off the shelf solution like what Bosch produces, but it's unlikely as for this particular project they will be prohibitively expensive. From what I've found, on the lower end those run about $40 a piece whereas I can get 5 of transducers for around $30 + $10-$15 for complimentary circuitry, if looking at pricing for one unit anyway. So the imperative is there for now at least to get it working with the present requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using relays as the T/R (transmit/receive) switch. Don't!

Perhaps you can work something in like this for a T/R switch.

[image: schematic]

**Transmit:** Current flows through the transducer and D1 & D2. Since the transmit voltage is 150 Vpp, the 1 V drop across the diodes is insignificant. The diodes protect the receiver input. Use switching diodes that can handle the current, perhaps along the line of a BAV99.

**Receive:** For receive to work, Q1 is set to off, Q2 is on. You may want to place a resistor across the diodes to dampen the transducer.

Comment: That's a great suggestion and makes a lot of sense, thanks for sharing that. I am skeptical about the relays but I thought I'd give them a go for the sake of simplicity. However, I am using solid state relays which as far as I understand are just a pair of photosensitive N FETs back to back, so in essence I have the same thing as above except Q1 and Q2 would be replaced with a pair of MOSFETS each. Do you still think there's an advantage to not using the relays and using discrete FETs and there's something else I'm not understanding or were you thinking I was using mechanical relays?

Comment: @ElPastor I would worry about the off capacitance of SSRs. I assumed the worst (mechanical), but didn't know what type of relay you were using since you didn't mention it.