Piezo T/R switch
I try to use single piezo as transceiver. Is this possible if i can T/R switch using FET or BJT ?
I found this schematich but not sure if it works.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252602894_Design_of_Pic-Controlled_Pulsed_Ultrasonic_Transmitter_for_Measuring_Gingiva_Thickness/figures?lo=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic

In somewhere nearby the blue cursor at right side echo signal must be showing but not. RC circuit below the tx is symbolling the PZT.



Why don't you run the circuit through a simulation tool (like most EEs do these days)?

i dont have enough parameters to simulate the piezo

Yes, it can work ... Just add Tx and Rx. Sometimes, a transfo is also used ...

See this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/667410/using-the-same-ultrasonic-transducer-for-tx-and-rx-in-distance-measurement

Do i have to drive the piezo at really high voltages ? I was trying to do with 5Vpp (arduino digitalwrite)

@alidemir If the range is 32 mm, as depicted in the oscillogram, you can't use 4 kHz (a number used in your previous post) as the wavelength is about 85 mm. Using a 40 kHz transducer, you may have a better chance if Q of the transducer is sufficiently low enough where the ringing has died down. At this range, you probably don't need much drive level, i.e., 5 V drive may be enough. You many need to put a resistor across the ceramic to lower the Q or use an acoustically absorbent backing to lower the Q.

So should i be able to measure echo on further distances like 20cm ? As i remember i also tried that but didnt get anything
